# Sequelize findAll() or findOne is not working

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I apologize for something that could be very simple to fix, I just cannot figure it out. I've used this code in another project before with the exact same layout and that project works, but on this project, it's not working.

As seen below in the code, I am doing a simple findAll() query. The database is connected perfectly fine but I keep getting this error no matter what I try.
[Error is here][1]

I wanted to double-check to see if it's because of me or if it's an issue with the latest release of sequelize, but I doubt it because I haven't seen any issues like this pop up yet.
But if nobody can see an issue, I will submit a bug ticket.

root/routes/ShopItems.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { ShopItems } = require('../models')


router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const data = await ShopItems.findAll()
    res.json(data)
})

module.exports = router
```

root/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const db = require('./models')
const { SECRET, PORT } = require('./temp_secret')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(session({
    secret: SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}))

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,GET,POST,content-type,Origin,Accept")
    req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,GET,POST,content-type,Origin,Accept")
    next()
})

// Routers
const ShopItemsRouter = require('./routes/ShopItems')
app.use('/shop', ShopItemsRouter)


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Running on ${PORT}`)
    })
})
```

root/models/index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

root/models/ShopItems.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const ShopItems = sequelize.define('shop_items', {
        item_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(),
            allowNull: false
        },
        item_description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(),
            allowNull: false
        },
        item_type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 'Single Item'
        },
        item_categories: {
            type: DataTypes.JSON(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '{}'
        },
        item_genres: {
            type: DataTypes.JSON(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '{}'
        },
        initial_item_price: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        item_discount: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        item_price: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        number_of_sales: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        }
    })
    return ShopItems
}
```

Thank you anyone that helps, I greatly appreciate it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBOTE.png

Answer (score 0):

In the ShopItems routes file you have

`const { ShopItems } = require('../models')`

The problem with this is that the index.js file (Which is what gets brought in with the above statement), does not export a ShopItems property. This is why your error message is saying "Cannot read properties of undefined", because in this case the ShopItems variable is returning undefined.

Without seeing your ShopItems model I can't say for sure if this will work, but if that model exists and is set up properly, you should be able to do:

`const db = require('../models')`

And then inside of the route method:

`const data = await db.ShopItems.findAll()`

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question with the shopitems model. I tried changing it to your idea and the issue was the same.

Comment: Is the error message exactly the same? If it still says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading findAll)", then I suspect your model code is breaking somehow, because it's reading ShopItems as undefined, but the db object is being exported properly from index.js. If it's the db object that's undefined, then there's probably an issue with the execution of the index.js.

Comment: Yes it's responding with the same error message. I really have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Seems extremely likely that something is wrong with the model. What SQL dialect are you using? JSON is not a valid datatype for some dialects. I also have never seen the STRING and INTEGER data types initialized with the () next to them before. Do you have a GUI or shell you can view the database with? If so, does sequelize.sync() actually create the ShopItems table in the database?